# I want to extract all decimal numbers from a string in python 3, how can I do that without using regex?

Tags: python, string, function, casting

I made this simple program with functions to calculate mean, median, and mode from a list of numbers. I want to select all the decimal numbers, whatever they are (10.00034, 1, $5.46, $0.90 or 0.5 for example from a string something like "5, 7 83 100, $5.07, and 7.834") from a string and cast them to float. How can I do that in Python 3? I want to capture all decimal numbers with leading zeros as floats including their leading zeros.

```
import string

def mode(x):
    if len(x) == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        theDictionary = {}
        for number in x:
            count = theDictionary.get(number, None)
            if count == None:
                theDictionary[number] = 1
            else:
                theDictionary[number] = count + 1
        theMaximum = max(theDictionary.values())
        for key in theDictionary:
            if theDictionary[key] == theMaximum:
                print("Mode: ", key)
                return key


def median(x):
    if len(x) == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        x.sort()
        midpoint = len(x) // 2
        print("Median: ", end=" ")
        if len(x) % 2 == 1:
            print(x[midpoint])
            med = x[midpoint]
        else:
            print((x[midpoint] + x[midpoint - 1]) / 2)
            med = (x[midpoint] + x[midpoint - 1]) / 2
        return med


def mean(x):
    if len(x) == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        theSum = 0
        theSum = float(theSum)
        for number in x:
            theSum = theSum + number
        average = theSum / len(x)
        print("Mean: ", average)
        return average


def main():
    lyst = []
    print ("Enter a list of numbers or enter to quit: ")
    numbers = input()
    if numbers == "":
        return 0
    else:
        lyst = numbers.split()
        lyst = [float(x) for x in lyst]
        print("List: ", lyst)
        mode(lyst)
        median(lyst)
        mean(lyst)
        main()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I tried a few things I found here on stackoverflow and they haven't worked, like for instance i tried:

```
def main():
    lyst = []
    print ("Enter a list of numbers or enter to quit: ")
    numbers = input()
    if numbers != "":
        for x in numbers.split():
            try:
                lyst.append(float(x))
            except ValueError:
                pass
        print("List: ", lyst)
        mode(lyst)
        median(lyst)
        mean(lyst)
        main()
    else:
        return 0
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to filter your input string. One way to do it:

```
in_txt = "5, 7 83 100, $5.07, and 7.834"
in_filt = [x if x in "0123456789.+-" else " " for x in in_txt]
in_join = str.join('', in_filt)
number = in_join.split()

print(in_filt, in_join, number, sep="\n")
```

this leaves numbers and +-. in your string intact, replaces anything else with space:

```
# in_filt
['5', ' ', ' ', '7', ' ', '8', '3', ' ', '1', '0', '0', ' ', ' ', ' ', 
 '5', '.', '0', '7', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '7', '.', '8', '3', '4']

# in_join
5  7 83 100   5.07      7.834

# number
['5', '7', '83', '100', '5.07', '7.834']
```

Then use `['5', '7', '83', '100', '5.07', '7.834']` and proceed with float conversion.

Leading zeros in strings that become floats (`'0004.242'`) won't *float* though - as number the leading 0 digits are not preserved.

---

This will still give you errors for f.e. `"2021.07.25"` but that is no float to begin with so you should keep your try/catch.

Comment: Thanks Patrick, this approach works very well.